# Configuring Tomcat 7 JDBC Pool with Spring results in CCE

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, connection-pooling, tomcat7

I'm using Spring 3.0.5, MSSQLServer 2008 (with JTDS) Tomcat 7.0.23. I am trying to move away from common's DBCP and tried the following in my application-config.xml

```
<bean id="ipeDS" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
    p:driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource"
    p:url="${url}"
    p:username="${username}"
    p:password="${password}"
    p:initialSize="${initial.size}"
    p:maxActive="${max.active}"
    p:jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"/>
```

This results in

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver`

Complete Stack Trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:243)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:176)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:662)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:465)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:130)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:112)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:99)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:123)
at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:168)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:375)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1842)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:902)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:398)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:99)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:236)
    ... 54 more

Any pointers will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look to me like `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` is not a compatible datasource?

I have configured a datasource using JDTS before using c3p0. heres the bean:

```
      <bean id="dataSource" 
        class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close" 
        p:driverClass=" net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
        p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc-url}" 
        p:user="${username}" 
        p:password="${password}"
        />
```

This is not the same driver class but as I've said I think the datasource class you are using is the issue

There are various other setups here: [Data access with JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)

Answer (score 4):

You want `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` as the [driver class name](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#driverImplementation).

Answer (score 0):

The p:driverClassName needs to the Jdbc Driver for the underlying database.  In this case, you need to specify the driver for MSSQL Server.